# Direct Streaming Method CopyTo does not find the end

Tags: vb.net, stream, server-sent-events

I am reading a SSE by using this method

```
    Public Shared Sub ReadStreamForever(ByVal stream As Stream)
    Dim encoder = New UTF8Encoding()
    Dim buffer = New Byte(2047) {}
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    While True
        If stream.CanRead Then
            Dim len As Integer = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 2048)
            counter = counter + 1
            If len > 0 Then
                Dim text = encoder.GetString(buffer, 0, len)
                SSEApplication.Push(text) 'Here I collect the text slices to a List(of string) object
            Else
                Exit While
            End If
        Else
            Exit While
        End If
    End While
    SSEApplication.writer() 'Here I write the content to a .txt file
End Sub
```

With my example data it takes about 2 seconds. I would prefer not to read the stream into memory though and tried this method

```
Public Shared Sub ReadStreamForever1(ByVal stream As Stream)

    Dim output As FileStream = File.OpenWrite("C:\Users\mini_dataset.txt")
    While True
        If stream.CanRead Then
            stream.CopyTo(output)
        Else
            Exit While
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

But the process ends up in an endless loop (I guess) at least to me it looks like the end of the stream can not be found. I can break the process after a few seconds and all the data are in the .txt file. Any idea what I can do to get the direct stream to file method working?

Comment: We don't know what stream you're passing into the method, which makes it harder to help. If you could provide a [mcve] it would be easier to help you.

Comment: [Stream.CanRead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.canread) tells you whether a stream supports reading. Since it's apparently readable, `While True` will go on forever. Use a [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor).

Comment: You are right. I commented everything out except for stream.CopyTo(output) and it works. Thanks. Do you want to make an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stream.CanRead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.canread) tells you whether a stream supports reading. Since it's apparently readable, `While True` will go on forever.
Let's verify whether the output [Stream.CanWrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.canwrite) instead.

```
Public Shared Sub ReadStreamForever1(ByVal stream As Stream)
    Using output As FileStream = File.OpenWrite("[Output file path]")
        If output.CanWrite Then
            stream.CopyTo(output)
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

If the process takes some time and you need to report its progress, you could [read the stream using a buffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read) (I didn't add any error checking but of course a try/catch block should be used):
(Here, with 100 parts division commonly used by a ProgressBar)

```
Public Sub ReadStreamForever1(ByVal stream As Stream)
    Dim BufferLength As Integer = 81920 'As the default stream buffer
    Dim Buffer(BufferLength) As Byte
    Dim BytesRead As Long = 0L

    Using output As FileStream = File.OpenWrite("[Output file path]")
        If output.CanWrite Then
            Dim Part As Long = stream.Length \ 100
            Dim PartCount As Integer = 0
            Dim read As Integer = 0
            Do
                read = stream.Read(Buffer, 0, BufferLength)
                If read = 0 Then Exit Do
                If (BytesRead / Part > PartCount) Then
                    PartCount += 1
                    'ReportWriteProgress(PartCount)
                End If
                output.Write(Buffer, 0, read)
                BytesRead += read
            Loop
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```